# How to configure Oracle Stored Procedures Returning RefCursor in biztalk

Tags: wcf, stored-procedures, cursor, biztalk

i'm trying to configure recieve location that execute stored procedure returning ref_cursor(no in params) with wcf-oracledb adapter.

PollingAction:
        `http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/APPS/PollingPackage/CNS_INV_4LOG_INTF_PKG/BizTalk_rec`

PoolingStatement:
`<BizTalk_rec xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/APPS/PollingPackage/CNS_INV_4LOG_INTF_PKG"></BizTalk_rec>`

and i'm getting this error: 
The adapter "WCF-OracleDB" raised an error message. Details "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: Unexpected start node "BizTalk_rec" with namespace
`http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/APPS/PollingPackage/CNS_INV_4LOG_INTF_PKG"`     found.

any idea what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Oracle, but my Polling Statement for a stored procedure is something like this on my environment:

```
<ns0:BizTalk_rec xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/Procedure" />
```

My Polling Action would be the following:

```
http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/APPS/PollingProcedure/BizTalk_rec
```

In my situation, this is a default stored procedure, so not part of a package as far as I know.

Mind you again: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but I managed to get it working nicely with this (off course my stored procedure name and DB name are slightly different)

Hope this helps!